# programmatically add color swatches to color attribute Magento2

Tags: magento2, plugin, cli, color-swatches, script

I am using Magento 2.1.10 and have around 580 different colors in my color attribute. Since the Javascript obviously has trouble showing all of them in the backend (does not matter which browser, message appears the script took too long and break up, can't increase my script time), and the color names with swatches can change sometimes, so I want to write a CLI plugin which updates the color attribute with color swatches through a CSV file. 
I already googled, tried different ideas and tested some scripts I found, but nothing really works.

I hope someone has an idea or maybe a working script which add a hexcode to the color attribute swatch. Creating the plugin for getting all information from the file is already built, but the important thing is missing to update the swatches. 
What do I mean with "color swatches"? I mean the small colored boxes in the frontend instead of the drop-down.

Thank you in advance